# How can I see how InnoDB stores my data, based on DB structure?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, innodb, database-schema

Is there any tool or command which shows how InnoDB stores my database, based on DB structure.
I want to see how InnoDB stores my table data. I want to change table structure to improve delete query.

I want to see how the structure effects the performance of delete query.

Comment: Do you mean where the physical files are stored?

Comment: I want to know, how it is storing the data. How many pages, etc.
basically DB stats.

Comment: ahsan, was the answer what you was looking for?

Comment: Isn't there any graphical tool, where i can see how the data is physically stored, in a specific table?
like how many rows are stored in a page?
And how changing the primary key makes difference to my table structure?

Comment: Dont think so, you could maybe query the performance schema to get addiontal info. use performance_schema; select * from events_statements_current;

Answer (score 3):

To check how it stores the data, you have to look into the folders of MySQL. Depending on operating system and loca setting it stores it per table or in just one big file.

To check the current status, execute

```
SHOW STATUS
```

You can also apply a WHERE to this like this

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name like '%pages%'
```

This will in details show any status with 'pages' in the variable name.

To check how big your system is i use this command, this breaks it into per table level.

```
SELECT 
table_name AS `Table`,
concat(round(sum(table_rows)/1000000,2),'M') '# of rows',
concat(round(sum(data_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') 'Size of data',
concat(round(sum(index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') 'Size of index',
concat(round(sum(data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') 'Total size',
round(sum(index_length)/sum(data_length),2) 'Index fraction'
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Is this what you are looking for?